# Export comments from Fortify Software Security Center

Tags: static-analysis, fortify

I would like to have the comments section of a finding on the Software Security Center website be exported in the excel report that is generated, to avoid having to edit FPRs as working on the SSC is much easier.

the version of SSC I am on is 23.1.2.0005

From what I can see the exported excel file does not show the comments column, I am unsure if there is some sort of setting or maybe even version of SSC I need to be on